# How to rerun my calculator program if a character that isn't 'c' for calculator or 'r' for rules is entered

Tags: c, cs50

I'm very new to programming. I'm using the cs50 IDE btw since I'm learning C on YouTube. I'm having trouble making it rerun the program when a letter that isn't 'c' or 'r' is entered.

Here's the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    //rules or calculator
    char c = get_char("Insert the letter c for access to the calculator.\nInsert the letter r for access to the rules.\n");
    //calculator access
    if (c == 'c')
    {
        //get first number
        float x = get_float("Enter the first number\n");
        //get the operation character
        char s = get_char("Enter the math operation character\n");
        //get second number
        float y = get_float("Enter the second number\n");
        //addition
        if (s == '+')
            {
                float z = x + y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
            }
        //division
        else if (s == '/')
            {
                float z = x / y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
            }
        //multiplication
        else if (s == '*')
            {
                float z = x * y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
            }
        //subtraction
        else if (s == '-')
            {
                float z = x - y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
            }
        //bug response
        else
            {
      printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
        }
    }
    //rule acess
    else if (c == 'r') 
        {
            printf("Choose 2 numbers and a math operator character. Make sure the numbers don't occupy more than 8 bits. Imprecision in floats might happen. Use these as math operator characters: +; -; /; *; otherwise it won't work.");
        }
    //bug response 2
    else 
        {
            printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't got a loop around the input and subsequent operations.  What does `get_char()` return when it encounters EOF?

Comment: Side note: Your indentation is inconsistent. After an `if` statement, you sometimes indent the `{` and sometimes you do not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm very new to programming. Can you please explain what EOF is and why I need a loop around the input? Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, I'll make sure to change that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The function [`get_char`](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.get_char) will return `CHAR_MAX` on error (which presumably also happens on end-of-file). However, I do not think that OP needs to worry about that.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel — no, I was not confused about `getchar()` vs `get_char()`.  I was asking what the `get_char()` function returns when it encounters the EOF (end-of-file) condition.  I had a strong suspicion that it was not going to return `EOF`.  (I'm not sure that `CHAR_MAX` is a good choice — it disenfranchises those who use ÿ in ISO 8859-1, for example. However, that's outside my control, your control, and the control of the OP.). And I think that the OP does have to worry about EOF since there isn't an option to exit and in any case, EOF can be signalled and should be handled appropriately.

Comment: Can I use goto to go back to a certain line so it runs again? If so how do I do that?

Comment: you can, but it's much better practice to use a loop

Comment: @yano how do I use a loop in this situation. I only want to rerun it if the person enters a character that is not 'c' or 'r'

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to repeat the line

```
char c = get_char("Insert the letter c for access to the calculator.\nInsert the letter r for access to the rules.\n");
```

until the input is valid, then you could add an infinite loop to the program and explicitly break out of this loop using the [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) statement once you determine that the input is valid.

If you want to do the same with the line

```
char s = get_char("Enter the math operation character\n");
```

then you could add an additional loop for that line to repeat, until the input is valid.

Here is a solution which adds a loop for both lines:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //loop forever until input is valid
    for (;;) //equivalent to while(1)
    {
        //rules or calculator
        char c = get_char("Insert the letter c for access to the calculator.\nInsert the letter r for access to the rules.\n");

        //calculator access
        if (c == 'c')
        {
            //loop forever until input is valid
            for (;;)
            {
                //get first number
                float x = get_float("Enter the first number\n");
                //get the operation character
                char s = get_char("Enter the math operation character\n");
                //get second number
                float y = get_float("Enter the second number\n");
                //addition
                if (s == '+')
                {
                    float z = x + y;
                    printf("%f\n", z);
                    break;
                }
                //division
                else if (s == '/')
                {
                    float z = x / y;
                    printf("%f\n", z);
                     break;
                }
                //multiplication
                else if (s == '*')
                {
                    float z = x * y;
                    printf("%f\n", z);
                    break;
                }
                //subtraction
                else if (s == '-')
                {
                    float z = x - y;
                    printf("%f\n", z);
                    break;
                }
                //bug response
                else
                {
                    printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        //rule acess
        else if (c == 'r') 
        {
            printf("Choose 2 numbers and a math operator character. Make sure the numbers don't occupy more than 8 bits. Imprecision in floats might happen. Use these as math operator characters: +; -; /; *; otherwise it won't work.");
            break;
        }
        //bug response 2
        else 
        {
            printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
        }
    }
}
```

In the comments section, you also asked about using the [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/goto) statement instead of a loop. This is possible too, but it generally considered bad programming practice.

Here is a version of your program that uses `goto` instead of additional loops:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
retry_1:

    //rules or calculator
    char c = get_char("Insert the letter c for access to the calculator.\nInsert the letter r for access to the rules.\n");

    //calculator access
    if (c == 'c')
    {
    retry_2:

        //get first number
        float x = get_float("Enter the first number\n");
        //get the operation character
        char s = get_char("Enter the math operation character\n");
        //get second number
        float y = get_float("Enter the second number\n");
        //addition
        if (s == '+')
        {
            float z = x + y;
            printf("%f\n", z);
        }
        //division
        else if (s == '/')
        {
            float z = x / y;
            printf("%f\n", z);
        }
        //multiplication
        else if (s == '*')
        {
            float z = x * y;
            printf("%f\n", z);
        }
        //subtraction
        else if (s == '-')
        {
            float z = x - y;
            printf("%f\n", z);
        }
        //bug response
        else
        {
            printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
            goto retry_2;
        }
    }
    //rule acess
    else if (c == 'r') 
    {
        printf("Choose 2 numbers and a math operator character. Make sure the numbers don't occupy more than 8 bits. Imprecision in floats might happen. Use these as math operator characters: +; -; /; *; otherwise it won't work.");
    }
    //bug response 2
    else 
    {
        printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
        goto retry_1;
    }
}
```

One problem with both solutions is that the line

```
float y = get_float("Enter the second number\n");
```

will be executed even when the user previously entered an invalid operator. It would probably be more meaningful to reprompt the user immediately for a valid operator, if it is invalid. However, this would mean that you must check the operator twice, once before the line quoted above and once afterwards:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //loop forever until input is valid
    for (;;) //equivalent to while(1)
    {
        //rules or calculator
        char c = get_char("Insert the letter c for access to the calculator.\nInsert the letter r for access to the rules.\n");

        //calculator access
        if (c == 'c')
        {
            //get first number
            float x = get_float("Enter the first number\n");
            //get the operation character
            char s;
            for (;;)
            {
                s = get_char("Enter the math operator\n");
                if (
                    s == '+' ||
                    s == '-' ||
                    s == '*' ||
                    s == '/'
                )
                {
                    //input is valid, so break out of loop
                    break;
                }

                printf( "Invalid operator!\n" );
            }
                 
            //get second number
            float y = get_float("Enter the second number\n");
            //addition
            if (s == '+')
            {
                float z = x + y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
                break;
            }
            //division
            else if (s == '/')
            {
                float z = x / y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
                break;
            }
            //multiplication
            else if (s == '*')
            {
                float z = x * y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
                break;
            }
            //subtraction
            else if (s == '-')
            {
                float z = x - y;
                printf("%f\n", z);
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        //rule acess
        else if (c == 'r') 
        {
            printf("Choose 2 numbers and a math operator character. Make sure the numbers don't occupy more than 8 bits. Imprecision in floats might happen. Use these as math operator characters: +; -; /; *; otherwise it won't work.");
            break;
        }
        //bug response 2
        else 
        {
            printf("Something went wrong. Are you sure you followed the rules?\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll change the code now.